# Фигурные скобки после создания объекта Java/Android

Tags: android, java

Здравствуйте , подскажите пожалуйста вот встретил такую конструкцию , не могу понять как она работает , почему после создания объекта открывается фигурная скобка и идет оверрайд метода. Объясните пожалуйста. 
Спасибо заранее.

```
OnClickListener oclBtn = new OnClickListener() {
               @Override
               public void onClick(View v) {
                  ...............

                 }
             };
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Это такая военная хитрость. Java позволяет не выделять новый класс с наследованием ради изменения одного метода, а переписать его для одного объекта на лету, так сказать. Если я правильно помню, это называется анонимный класс. По сути создается объект класса, наследующего OnClickListener с переопределенным методом onClick(), но не имеющего имени.

Comment: Понял , спасибо большое, то есть так бы пришлось делать примерно следующее . 
public class MyListener extends OnClickListener {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
.........
}
};
А затем уже работать с объектами этого класса ? 

Еще вопрос такой , это только один метода так можно переопределить ? 
Или несколько ?

Comment: Можно несколько.

Comment: Если правильно говорить, то нужно переопределить ровно столько методов, сколько требует тип. В данном случае - OnClickListener. Меньше определить не получиться - будут методы без реализации. Больше определить также не получиться (в данном случае), так как OnClickListener - интерфейс (то есть, все методы абстрактны).